# How to remove zip postal code and country from checkout form?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping-address, billing

I want to remove **zip/postal code and country** from checkout page.

I removed them from **billing.phtml** file successfully. But when submit checkout data it shows alert that "**country**" and "**zip/postal**" code required.

I want to remove them from **shipping.phtml** file also.

Comment: your store is selling product for one country or multiple country ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to Configuration -> General -> Country Options
2. Select only a **single country** (your default country)
3. Select **all country** for the field `Postal Code is Optional for the following countries`.
4. Update `eav_attribute` table and set `is_required = 0` if `attribute_code = 'postcode'`
5. You can remove the `Zip/Postal Code` fields on templates.
6. Replace `Country` fields with this:

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="country_id" value="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/default'); ?>"/>

   <!-- Original Country Field
   <div class="field">
       <label for="billing:country_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php /*echo $this->__('Country') */?></label>
       <div class="input-box">
           <?php /*echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing') */?>
        </div>
   </div>
   -->
   ```

Comment: i want to remove them from shipping page also .how ?

Comment: As said on the steps, you would have to modify the templates. In your case, you would have to find what template is used on your shipping page, then follow the steps above.

Comment: You're welcome, Mohamed Maree

Comment: I want to removed only country..your code in removed country and state both..

Comment: I think you can work on that just fine. Find the template and remove the HTML of state only, and leave the country. You're a developer, right?

Answer (score 0):

For country option just put a style on it as `display:none`;

**E.g. Note**: This option is valid if you have selected by default country option from admin.

```
<div class="field" style="display:none;">
   <label for="billing:country_id" class="required"><em>*</em>
  <?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
  <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```