# how can I remove some fields on the checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I want to remove some Fields in **shipping and billing addresses** in the checkout page in magento 1.

**like: company , middle name , region , fax , ZIP code....**

How can I do It using programatically.

magento 1.9.2

Comment: `System -> Configuration -> CUSTOMERS -> Customer Configuration ->Name and Address Options` change setting

Answer (score 0):

You need to development a module and create a `system.xml` file and put the on/off options which you want to disable in the **checkout page**.

See the following answer

[how to remove zip postal code and country from checkout form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/71807/3368)

Its may be help for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove **zipcode** as these are mandatory fields by default.

For other field, You can do it by commentating the corresponding phtml file in your theme.

For **company, region, fax** comment corresponding fields in the file template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml

For **middle name** comment corresponding fields in the file template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml