# how to remove zipcode text box from magento checkout page

Tags: magento2

As per the title, you can realize that its a very old and repetitive question, but actually I could not find a solid answer !!.how to remove zipcode from checkout page

Comment: you try this :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71803/how-to-remove-zip-postal-code-and-country-from-checkout-form

Comment: You can try this --> http://serbu.me/2016/10/01/how-to-remove-postcode-field-from-magento2-checkout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create **checkout_index_index.xml** in your module and paste the below code :

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Output :**

[image]

Clean cache and check it.

Comment: I have extended the sales order grid on my custom module, can you please let me know how to remove/customize buttons, filters, search box, etc on the custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Override `checkout_index_index.xml` and remove

```
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
     <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
     <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
     <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
         <item name="validate-digits" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
     </item>
</item>
```